# Sr-iov must be vlan?

Tags: virtualization, libvirt

I am trying to use sr-iov to pass packets to vm
Is this obliged to work with vlan when working with sr-iov?

If not, according to what will the different vf receive the packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packet is sent to the right controller virtual function according to mac address and vlan tag
If no vlan defined, i beleive it will be only by mac adress